# Hello Word Controller in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to create a new module in a magento 1.7 installation. The module defines a new controller and route.

I created the module, and for testing purposes I created a helper with it, which works, proving that the module is loading. However, the route that the module is supposed to create just 404s.

I created all the files below and cleared the cache, but when I go to any of the following urls, they are all 404:

- mysite/recurringsetup
- mysite/recurringsetup/index/index
- mysite/index.php/recurringsetup
- mysite/index.php/recurringsetup/index/index

I know the module itself is loading because to test I included a call to `Mage::helper('recurringsetup')->work()` in the head template which outputs correctly.

I have no idea what's wrong or how to troubleshoot it.

Here's the code for the files:

**controller**:

```
<?php //app/code/local/NewHope/RecurringSetup/controllers/IndexController.php

class NewHope_RecurringSetup_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

?>
```

**config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--/app/code/local/NewHope/RecurringSetup/etc/config.xml-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <NewHope_RecurringSetup>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NewHope_RecurringSetup>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <recurringsetup>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>NewHope_Recurring</module>
                    <frontName>recurringsetup</frontName>
                </args>
            </recurringsetup>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newhope_recurringsetup>
                <class>NewHope_RecurringSetup_Model</class>
            </newhope_recurringsetup>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <recurringsetup>
                <class>NewHope_RecurringSetup_Helper</class>
            </recurringsetup>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**helper**:

```
class NewHope_RecurringSetup_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

    function work()
    {
        return 'works';
    }


}
```

**model**:

```
<?php //app/code/local/NewHope/RecurringSetup/Model/Observer.php

class NewHope_RecurringSetup_Model_Observer
{

}
```

**global config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--app/etc/modules/NewHope_RecurringSetup.xml-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <NewHope_RecurringSetup>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </NewHope_RecurringSetup>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was a simple fix! in the **config.xml** file there's a line that reads

```
<module>NewHope_Recurring</module>
```

It should read

```
<module>NewHope_RecurringSetup</module>
```

Leaving the question for posterity.

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer once the option is available.